# How To Create a Remote Views Search Form - D7

Tags: 7, views, forms, panels, search

I have overridden the default Drupal /search page with a panel view that is listing users. In this view, users can be filtered by gender, age, location, etc - and it's working quite well! I have paired Contextual Filters and exposed Filter Criteria enabled to allow GET variables to be passed to the view while still allowing for a Filter Criteria fallback. Achieving this took a few experimental patches.

Now I need to place a search form on the home page that has a few of these filter options. This form needs to direct users to the /search page and take with it whatever the user enters. I've tried using the [Exposed Filters Block](http://s1l.org/views-3-exposed-filters-block) but doing so removes the filters from the /search page entirely and negates the view header and footer which are unfortunately essential to the view.

Creating a basic HTML GET action form that sends users to the /search page works well, but that's a nasty long URL and I would prefer to keep this within Drupal. It seems that changing this form to use POST instead of GET does not work.

Is there some way to create a stripped-down form that leads into this search view? Using the Forms API would be nice but I'm open to any other solutions presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would suggest writing your own form in a block which you can place on the home page. I don't see anything wrong with writing the form in HTML - though if you [generate your form the Drupal way](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/form_api/7) using the [Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) then you'll ensure you get consistent themeing across your site, you'll be protected against [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and so on. How to use the Form API is beyond the scope of a single question ;
2. There is a module that allows you to use POST queries with views exposed filters : http://drupal.org/project/views_expost - hopefully this should deal with your long URL problem.

Comment: This is perfect - I'm right at home with the Forms API. Thank you!!